# Виджеты Опросов ВКонтакте налезают друг на друга

Tags: php, javascript, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, виджет

На сайт добавил Опросы из VK. Сам код Опроса запихнул в MySQL.

Добавил два Опроса, а они "вылезли" друг на друга.

В двух MySQL одинаковый код:

```html
<!-- Put this script tag to the <head> of your page -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?137"></script>
<!-- Put this div tag to the place, where the Poll block will be -->
<div id="vk_poll"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
VK.Widgets.Poll("vk_poll", {width: 300, height: 150}, "252365263_929139d2b1c4c5748c");
</script><br>
```

```
while ($myrow3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)){
echo "
<div class='news'>


".$content."

<p>
    <table class='info'>
        <td><img src='img/clock.png'></td>  
        <td>".$date."</td>  
    </table>
</p>
</div>
<hr bgcolor='gray' width='100%'>";
}
```

В подключении к базе всё ОК:

[image: Скриншот отображения Опросов]

Comment: Т.е. у вас два одинаковых виджета, вставляющиеся в дивы с одинаковыми id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно, проблема в том, что вы инициализируете виджеты в один и тот же блок.

Через цикл у вас создаются два блока с одинаковым ID:

```
<div id="vk_poll"></div>
<div id="vk_poll"></div>
```

При выполнении этого кода, вы помещаете всё в блок с ID'ом `vk_poll` (первый параметр):

```
VK.Widgets.Poll("vk_poll", {width: 300, height: 150}, "252365263_929139d2b1c4c5748c");
```

Но дело в том, что, согласно спецификации HTML, на странице не должны находиться два элемента с одинаковыми атрибутами `id`, из-за чего оба виджета криво инициализируются в первый `<div>`.

Очевидное решение проблемы — изменить код примерно так:

```
<div id="vk_poll1"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
VK.Widgets.Poll("vk_poll1", {width: 300, height: 150}, "252365263_929139d2b1c4c5748c");
</script>

<div id="vk_poll2"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
VK.Widgets.Poll("vk_poll2", {width: 300, height: 150}, "252365263_929139d2b1c4c5748c");
</script>
```

---

Также я советую вам пересмотреть реализацию вашего приложения, потому что как минимум хранить в базе данных JavaScript и HTML — зачастую плохая идея. В идеале вы должны хранить в БД только ID опроса, а именно эту часть: `252365263_929139d2b1c4c5748c`.

А еще не надо `<script type="text/javascript" src="//vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?137"></script>` дважды встраивать в страницу.